# construct map $ X \to BG $ associated to principal $ G $ bundle $ F \to X $ explicitly combinatorically

Tags: algebraic-topology, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let  $  G  $  be a discrete group and   $ X  $  paracompact topological space. The classifying space   $ BG $  classifies isomorphy classes principal bundles over  $ X  $  via

$$ [ X, BG]  \cong    PrinG(X)/Isom , [f] \to f^* \pi $$ where the brackets on the left denote the homotopy classes of maps     $ X \to BG $  and  $ \pi: EG \to BG $ the universal bundle. Since the classifying classifying space is only unique up to homotopy there are several ways to construct it. Arguebly in case of discrete group $  G  $ there is a kind of canonical realization of   $ BG  $  as a  $  \triangle $-complex whose $n$-simplices are given by  $[g_0,g_1,...,g_n]$ glued together in the obvious way. (we are using here the notion of Delta complex in Hatcher's sense)

More precisely the universal bundle $EG$ carries structure of a $\triangle$-complex
whose $n$-simplices are the ordered $(n + 1)$ tuples
$[g_0, ... ,g_n]$ of elements of $G$. As
quotient space the classifing space $BG=EG/G$ inherits structure $\triangle$-complex where a $n$-simplex $BG$ can be written uniquely in the form $[g_1 \vert g_2\vert  ... \vert g_n]:= 
G \cdot [e_G, g_1, g_1g_2,..., g_1,.., g_n]$. For details see p 89 in Hatcher's book on algebraic topology.

Assume now  $  X  $   be a   $ \triangle$-complex and   $ F \to X  $ be  a principal $G$-bundle.

**Question:** Is it possible to construct combinatorically in explicit terms from this $G$-bundle $ F $ a simplicial map of  $ \triangle $-complexes $X \to BG$ (i.e. by assigning to which $ n $-simplices of $ BG $ are mapped $n$-simplices of $ X$) which gives a kind of " natural" representantative of the homotopy class of $ X \to BG $ which
corresponds via the correspondence above to isomorphism class
of $F \to X$? In other words the question is how to construct combinatorically the map  $  PrinG(X)/Isom \to [ X, BG]  $  in other direction in case  $   X  $  combinatorically 'nice' ?

A short remark on the reason for dealing with $\triangle$-complexes intead of combinatorically more simpler simplicial complexes: Seemingly even though $ EG$ in Hatchers book is realised as simplicial complex, the classifying space $ BG $ in the way Hatcher constructed it as quotient of $ EG $carries only structure of a $\triangle$-complex because it involves boundary identifications which are not allowed for simplicial complexes (Here my reference is Greg Friedman's An Elementary illustrated Introduction to Simplicial Sets). It might be possible - I dont knot - that $ BG $ might be also endowed with structure of a cimplicial complex, but this would then differ from Hatcher's. So  doubt if it's possible here to consider simplicial complexes first as 'simplified' case.

**Here are a few loose ideas what I tried so far: **

One idea how to manage it in the case $X$ is one dimensional, ie
consists of vertices and $1$-simplices.

I think we can assume that every loop contains at least *three* vertices,
if not, subdivide any $1$-simplex beeing part of the loop into
three new $1$-simplices:

$\bullet$-------$ \bullet$  subdivide into $\bullet$----$\bullet$----$\bullet$----$\bullet$

(why we do it? To avoid troubles with transition functions on
the intersections of trivializing cover; see later)

Now, we choose a cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $X$, over which the principal
$G$-bundle $E \to X$ trivialize, ie $E \vert _{U_i} \cong U_i \times G$.

Now we make several assumptions on this cover which look rather
realizable if $X$ is dimension one, but possibly fail in bigger
dimension (that's why I think this approach only works in dimension one):

We choose a cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in X_0} $ indexed by the set
$X_0= \{v_1, v_2,..., \} $ of vertices of $X$ and require
that every member $U_i$ saisfies following properties:

1. $v_i \in U_i$ and $v_j \not \in U_i$ for every other vertex $v_j \neq v_i$
2. $U_i$ and $U_j$ have a non trivial intersection - which in that
   case is isomorphic to an open interval $ \cong (0,1)$ - if and only if
   vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent, ie form the boundary of
   a $1$-simplex $[v_i, v_j]$; in this case the intersection
   $U_i \cap U_j \cong (0,1) $ is completely contained in
   thee *inner* of this $1$-simplex $[v_i, v_j]$

(Attention: That's where we use the assumption that every
loop in $X$ contains at least *three* vertices. Otherwise
two unwanted things could happen: one thing that a $1$-simplex
having a single vertex as it's boundary could be contained
completely in a $U_i$ (we don't want it) and secoundly
*two* or more different $1$-simplices having as boundary the same
two vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ - in that case the intersection
$U_i \cap U_j$ would be not an open interval, but a union of open
intervalls; one for each $1$-simplex. That would cause troubles
with the contruction of the map $X \to BG$ later.)

Recall, that in an simplicial complex a higher simplex is completly
determined by it's vertices; in a $\triangle$-complex there
could be different higher simplices having same set of vertices,
eg $1$-complex
$v_1$---$w$---$v_2$ after identifying
vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$. And such behavior would cause problems when we try to to associate to a $1$-simplex  of $X$ a $1$-simplex in $BG$.

Obviously every $U_i$ is contractible, since by construction
it's isomorphic to a bouquet of intervalls $[1, 0)$ (one
for each $1$-simplex having $v_i$ as one of it's boundary points),
after identifying the left $1$'s with the vertex point $v_i$.

Now we construct the map $f:X \to BG$: the $\triangle$-complex of
$BG$ in Hatcher's book has only one $vertex$ $[*]$, so we map every vertex
of $X$ to it. What to do with the $1$-simplices of $X$?

Let $[v_i,v_j]$ a $1$-simplex with boundary points $v_i, v_j$.
Then there exist a unique non trivial intersection of
the covering pieces $U_i$, which is contained in $[v_i,v_j]$,
obviously by construction $U_i \cap U_j \cong (0,1)$.

The [transition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Transition_functions) $g_{ij}: U_i \cap U_j \to G$ satisfying the patching isomorphism $U_i \cap U_j \times G \to U_i \cap U_j \times G, 
(u, g) \mapsto (u, g_{ij}(u) \cdot g)$
is determined up to homotopy and since $U_i \cap U_j$ contractible,
$g_{ij}$ can be identified with an element in $G$.
So we map the $1$-simplex $[v_i,v_j]$ to the $1$-simplex $[g_{ij}]$
of $BG$.

**Problems:**

-does this construction give the $G$-bundle $E$ back? ie
$E = f^*EG$? (Here we have to check that the transition function
$g_{ij}: U_i \cap U_j \to G$ restricted to $U_i \cap U_j \cap f^{-1}(V_k \cap 
V_m) $ is given by $g_{ij}(u)= h_{km}(f(u)) $ where
$V_k, V_m \subset BG$ are arbitrary two open subsets of $BG$ over which
the universal bundle $\pi: EG \to BG$ trivializes, ie $EG \vert _{V_k}$
and $h_{km}: V_k \cap V_m \to G$ is the associated transition function.
I not know how to check $g_{ij}(u)= h_{km}(f(u)) $. What is
the transition function of $EG \to BG$ and is there a canonical choice
of trivialiving cover $\{V_k\}_{k \in K}$ to $\pi: EG \to BG$?

Can this construction generalized to higher dimensional $X$?
Observe, that for $X$ of dimension $1$ I have choosen a very special
trivializing cover. I'm not sure if there is always possible to
choose a cover satisfying the same conditions for higher dimensional
$X$, eg a octahedron.

If the space $X$ becomes even more complicated (eg of dimension
bigger that $1$ and it contain loops which are boundaries of higher simplices,
my construction above seems to be irreparable.

Another naive idea was to discard all simplices of dimension $\le 2$
for the moment and perform the construction from above on the $1$-skeleton
of $X$, but I doubt if it's possible to extend it to the map
$X \to BG$ naturally, since in case of $\triangle$-complexes
the higher dimensional simplces are almost never determined
by vertices & $1$-simplices like that's the case for
simplicial complexes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I'm not completly sure if that's the best way to do it but lets try:  we can regard a circle as as a triangle with removed inner. so it consists of three vertices $ v_i$ and three 1-simplices $(v_i, v_j)$. We assume that covered by three intervalls $ I_i $ over which the G-bundle trivializes and each of these intervalls contains exactly one vertex $ v_i$. The intersections of each two of these intervalls are intervalls too and are completely contained in a unique 1-simplex, namely $I_j \cap I_j \subset  (v_i, v_j)$.

Comment: Each intersection of two such intervalls also determines a transition function, ie an element $ g_{ij} \in G$. Then we map the 1-simplex  $(v_i, v_j)$ to $ [1 \vert g_{ij}]$, a 1-simplex of BG. Is the idea ok?

Comment: If that works, then this answers the case where X is 1-dimensional. I have no clue how to extend it to higher dimensional $\triangle$-complexes

Comment: If we try to mimic to same approach like for the circle, seemingly the resulting maps $ X \to BG$ would be completely determined only by what is going on 1-skeleta, and that sounds strange...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: above I added a more precise idea how that could work for $X$ one dimensional $\triangle$-complex. hope it's not explained too confusingly. One point in your remark I not completely understand: you wrote that the bundle is trivial over $1$-simplices. If $X$ would be a simplicial complex, then I aggree with you, there every 1-simplex has two **different** vertices as boundaries, so it's homotopic to a line and therefore contractible. But in a $\triangle$-complex there could be some weird identifications performed on the boundary inside $X$,

Comment: eg the two boundary points of the 1-simplex could be identified, and then the 1-simplex lives as a loop inside $X$ and therefore not contractible. See for example the construction of $BG$ in Hatcher's book. Or do I missing here your point?

Comment: On my wrong 'jump' that everything might be defined on level of 1-skeleton: yes, that's wrong, that was exactly the picture of a simplicial complex which I had before in mind, where the simplices are determined only by their vertices. But clearly that's wrong for $\triangle$-complexes, indeed for example there could the a complex $v_1$---- $w$----$v_2$ which vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ identified. Then the two 1-simples are different although have same vertices, so indeed what I wrote was nonsense.

Comment: About the checkng that the construction of map $X \to BG$ for 1-dimnsional: Do you know if there exist a natural cover of $BG$ over which $EG$ trivializes? To show that my $f: X \to BG$ gives via pullbck the $F \to X$ back, I have to check that $f^*EG$ has the the same transtion function as $F \to X$ over trivializtions. I explained in more detail above in the "Problems" paragraph how I intend to compare transition functions of $F$ and $f^*EG$. But for this I need to know the transition function of $EG$ and therefore a trivializing cover. Do you know if there is a natural way to construct one?

Comment: @Mariano: but why do you think that $BG$ (in sense of Hatcher's construction) is a simplicial complex? The main difference between simplicial complexes and $\triangle$-complexes that in the latter there is more flexibility in identifying the boundary. For example if $[v_1, v_2]$ is a 1-simplex with vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ of a simplicial complex, then it would be not allowed to identify these two vertices, on the other hand, in a $\triangle$-complex it would be legitim to identify these. (that's the crucial difference between simplicial and $\triangle$-complexes,

Comment: see eg Greg Friedman's An elementary illustrated introduction to simplicial sets, part 2.4. And in BG there is only one vertex, so it cannot be a simplicial complex (on the other hand EG is one). So yes, I agree with you, that if BG would be a simplicial complex it would be reasonable to start with the case that $X$ is simplicial too, but if my argumentation above make sense, then it seems that BG is an example of an $\triangle$-complex which is *not* a simplicial complex

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong and BG is a simplicial complex, but then the simplicial stucture on BG is definitely constructed in another way than Hatcher did it in his book, ie not by inheriting the structure of EG by passing to quotient, as there happens exactly that kindof identifications which are allowed for $\triangle$-complexes, but forbidden for simplicials

Comment: could you sketch how you intend to tesselate the BG in order to endow it with structure of a simplicial complex? maybe this resolves my confusion

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I studied these things, and principal bundles always baffled me (while vector bundles made more sense somehow), so maybe the following is nonsense. But I thought I'd give it a shot:

You might want to think about, say, circle bundles over the 2-sphere, so $X$ is $S^2$. There are $\mathbb Z$ of these, with the integer corresponding to the degree of the clutching-function on the equator.

If you represent $S^2$ as an octahedron, then you have to represent those uncountably many things by a map from a few triangles to BG, which you've represented as a finite simplicial complex. There are only finitely many such maps.

I feel pretty sure that you need to include subdivision as a possible step in building your explicit combinatorial map.

Comment: the octahedron example is great, I feel that it provides the right intuition what is going on there. Say we have a G-bundle and there is a covering $ \{ U_i \}_i$ of  of the octahedron X such that over each $ U_i $ the bundle trivializes  with additional mild assumption that each  $ U_i $ contains exactly one vertex $ v_i $ of the octahedron. how can we we associate to the bundle canonically a map to BG? Naively I would ignore the 2-simplices and try the same idea as in the comments above using transitions functions along the intersection of two   $ U_i $ but I'm not sure if it works here.

Comment: It should additionally be required that every intersection $ U_i \cap U_j $ which determine a transition function $ g_{ij} $ can be related to a unique 1-simplex  of the octahedron in order to map this 1-simplex to the 1-simplex $ [1 \vert g_{ij}] $ of BG, but I think that for a 2-dimensional complex this might not always work like in case of a 1-dimensional complex, eg a circle

Comment: Or do you see another natural way how to associate a map $ X \to BG $ to a given principal G-bundle in the case X octahedron?

Comment: by the way: as far as I understand the motivation behind performing an extra subdivision correctly, the aim is that the bundle trivializes over every simplex of maximal dimension, right?

Comment: To your last question... yes. But if you want to wrap a circle (the equator of the octahedron) multiple times around some circle in BG , you need at least 3 edges for every "wrap", so having just four edges won't cut it. Hence the need for subdivision. To be honest, I can't quite make sense of your other 3 comments because I haven't had my first shot of caffeine, and I'm not going to be able to spend any more time on this for at least a week. But I'm glad it might have pushed you in the right direction.

Comment: one another (maybe rather important) point in your answer confuses me. You mentioned that the model of $ BG $ I presented ( that's from Hatcher's book) is a simplicial complex. But I think that that the point is that - in contrast to $ EG $ -  the BG in the book is given as $\triangle$-complex, that dramatically differs from simplicial complexes  in the way you have more freedom in identifying the boundaries, cp with Greg Friedman's survey  An elementary illustrated introduction to simplicial sets, part 2.4.

Comment: Why is this important? Because any simplex of a simplicial complex is uniquely determined by it's set of vertices, for $ \triangle$-complex thats not true, as an example in Friedman's survey demonstrates. In turn, a combinatorical map between simplicial complexes would be uniquely determined by images of vertices, since this would disctate how it must be in unique way(!) to be prolonged to higher simplices by what I said above  about the difference between simplicial and Delta simplices

Comment: But - even if we allow for sake of simplicity to assume  $ X $ to be a simplicial complex - the question is if it's legal to assume this for BG too? Maybe $BG$ there exist some realization of a model of BG as simplicial complex - I honestly don't know it - but then this would be different from that one that Hatcher gave in his book, which is a futher example of a $ \triangle$-complex which is not a simplicial complex, since for exmple all vertices of all simplices are identifies. Maybe after appropriate subdivisions this could be turned into a simplicial complex, at least this sounds plausible

Comment: but then the 1-simplices of BG cannot more be bookkeeped by elements of $G$ anymore. Then there is no more a "canonical" way to map the transition functions of the overlaps of trivializing covers of $ X $ -note these are exactly represented by elements $ g \in G $ to 1-simplices of G. So I don't now else the map $ X \to BG $ could be naturally constrcted from informations that a given principal G bundle $ F \to X$ contains. Indeed, the transition functions are exactly the combinatorical data of such principal bundle, so goal is to uncover how this data encode the corresponding map $ X \to BG $