# Construct a trivializing cover of universal principal $G$-bundle $EG \to BG$

Tags: algebraic-topology, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

In Hatcher's book  on algebraic topology (p 89) the universal bundle $EG$ ($G$ discrete group) carries structure of a $\triangle$-complex whose $n$-simplices are the ordered $(n + 1)$ tuples
$[g_0, ... ,g_n]$ of elements of $G$. As
quotient space the classifing space $BG=EG/G$ inherits structure $\triangle$-complex where a $n$-simplex $BG$ can be written uniquely in the form $[g_1 \vert g_2\vert  ... \vert g_n]:= 
G \cdot [e_G, g_1, g_1g_2,..., g_1,.., g_n]$.

My question is if there is a natural way to choose a trivializing cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of the universal principal $G$-bundle $EG \to BG$, ie a family of open subsets of $BG$ such that $EG \vert \_{U_i} \cong U_i \times G$ and what are the the associated transition functions $h_{ij}: U_i \cap U_j \to G$ used for patching functions $ U_i \cap U_j \times G \to U_i \cap U_j \times G, (u,g) \mapsto (u, h_{ij}(u)g)$.

The question is closely connected to a problem appearing in a construction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607372/construct-map-x-to-bg-associated-to-principal-g-bundle-f-to-x-expl)

Comment: now posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438682